# Return all the data using a procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am creating a dynamic stored procedure that if a user supplies a vision id it returns only data linked to the id but if a user don't supply any vision ID it must return everything. So I have written my stored proc as below and this seems to work well:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Values_Select]

    @VisionId NVARCHAR(50) = '*'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    IF ISNULL(@VisionId, '') = ''
    BEGIN
        SET @VisionId = '*'
    END


    SELECT      Id, 
                VisionId, 
                Date, 
                Time, 
                [Value], 
                Checked, 
                CheckedTimestamp, 
                Vision_Name 

    FROM        dbo.viw1
    WHERE       VisionID = @VisionId OR @VisionId = '*'

END
```

My question is whether this is the best way to do it? Will I not suffer from parameter sniffing later on?  I am not convinced to put this code in my production environment yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need a stored procedure for this? You can just change `@VisionId = '*'` to `@VisionId IS NULL` and then it is a simple `SELECT` query.

Comment: Don't do this. Such [`catch-all` queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) result in bad performance. You don't get any extra performance by using a stored procedure. Any performance boost comes because the server can reuse the execution plans created for previous queries, whether they are in stored procedures or not. With a `catch-all` query though, that execution plan can be wrong - a plan generated when the parameter is empty will probably scan the entire table, not using any indexes. That plan will be reused even if you pass a value in a subsequent call

Answer (score 1):

Avoid such stored procedures if possible. If you don't need that parameter, don't even emit the `WHERE` clause. This is trivial to do with ORM-generated queries - just don't add the `.Where()` call. That's the best solution.

Such [catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) result in bad performance. You don't get any extra performance by using a stored procedure. Any performance boost comes because the server can reuse the execution plans created for previous *queries* (not stored procedures), whether they are in stored procedures or not.

With a catch-all query though, that execution plan can be wrong - a plan generated when the parameter is empty will scan the entire table, not using any indexes. That plan will be reused even if you pass a value in a subsequent call. On the other hand, a plan generated when the parameter has a value may use an index even when it's not needed.

[One way to fix this](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/) would be to add [WITH RECOMPILE](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/12/recompile-hints-and-execution-plan-caching/) to the stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Values_Select]

    @VisionId NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT      Id, 
                ...
    FROM        dbo.viw1
    WHERE       VisionID = @VisionId OR @VisionId IS NULL

END
```

The server will generate a new execution plan for all queries in the stored procedure each time it runs. This way you lose any benefits from execution plan caching.

Another option is to use `RECOMPILE` as a query hint. This allows recompiling only the statements that need it :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Values_Select]

    @VisionId NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT      Id, 
                ...
    FROM        dbo.viw1
    WHERE       VisionID = @VisionId OR @VisionId IS NULL WITH OPTION(RECOMPILE)

END
```

Another possibility is to generate **parameterized** dynamic SQL, adding the `WHERE` clause only when needed. It's a lot easier and safer to let an ORM do that though :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Values_Select]

    @VisionId NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @sSQL NVARCHAR(2000), @Where NVARCHAR(1000) = ''
    SET @sSQL = 'SELECT Id,.... FROM dbo.view1 '           -- Notice the trailing space

    IF @VisionId is not null
        SET @Where = @Where + 'AND VisionId= @_VisionId '  -- Trailing space here too
    -- Other optional parameters

    IF LEN(@Where) > 0
    SET @sSQL = @sSQL + 'WHERE ' + RIGHT(@Where, LEN(@Where)-3)

    EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL,
        N'@_VisionId nvarchar(50), ...',   -- parameter names
        @_VisionId = @VisionId, ...        -- parameter values
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Stored Procedure. You could do this like this:

```
 SELECT      Id, 
            VisionId, 
            Date, 
            Time, 
            [Value], 
            Checked, 
            CheckedTimestamp, 
            Vision_Name 

FROM        dbo.viw1
WHERE       @VisionId IS NULL OR VisionID = @VisionId
```

If you prefere to use Stored Procidure you could use bellow to better performance:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Values_Select]

    @VisionId NVARCHAR(50) = '*'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    IF ISNULL(@VisionId, '') = ''
    BEGIN
        SELECT  Id, 
                VisionId, 
                Date, 
                Time, 
                [Value], 
                Checked, 
                CheckedTimestamp, 
                Vision_Name 

      FROM      dbo.viw1
    END
    ELSE
      SELECT    Id, 
                VisionId, 
                Date, 
                Time, 
                [Value], 
                Checked, 
                CheckedTimestamp, 
                Vision_Name 

      FROM      dbo.viw1
      WHERE     VisionID = @VisionId
    END    
END
```

Comment: BTW if the OP didn't use a stored procedure, there would be no need for `@VisionID is NULL`. The `Where` clause can be eliminated if it's not needed

Answer (score 0):

using this Query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Values_Select]

    @VisionId NVARCHAR(50) = Null
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT      Id, 
                VisionId, 
                Date, 
                Time, 
                [Value], 
                Checked, 
                CheckedTimestamp, 
                Vision_Name 

    FROM        dbo.viw1
    WHERE       ( @VisionId is null OR VisionID = @VisionId )

END
```

Comment: This is logically exactly the same as OP's version. You just left out the trivial replacement of null with '*'.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic Query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Values_Select]
    @VisionId NVARCHAR(50) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
        SELECT      Id, 
                    VisionId, 
                    Date, 
                    Time, 
                    [Value], 
                    Checked, 
                    CheckedTimestamp, 
                    Vision_Name 
        FROM        dbo.viw1    
    '
    IF ISNULL(@VisionId, '') <> ''  
    SET @Query += '  WHERE VisionID = ''' + @VisionId + ''''
    EXEC(@Query)
END
```

Comment: **Parameterized** dynamic SQL is a valid solution to catch-all query performance issues provided they use. You already use `IF`, you can make different calls to `sp_executesql` in each branch, with or without a parameter

Comment: BTW without parameterization, this is a bad answer. *With* it, it's a good one

Comment: Need Values_Select output in another sp?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is called "parameterized queries" or "dynamic search conditions". As you can see, all of the solutions refer to either of two ways:

1) dynamic sql

2) using `@var is null or @var=field`

If you really want to dig into this, in my opinion, [the article of Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) is the best there is.

Answer (score 0):

I quite like this way (building on @Khalid's answer):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Values_Select]

    @VisionId NVARCHAR(50) = '%'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT      Id, 
                VisionId, 
                Date, 
                Time, 
                [Value], 
                Checked, 
                CheckedTimestamp, 
                Vision_Name 

    FROM        dbo.viw1
    WHERE       VisionID like @VisionId

END
```

If you don't like the idea of them being able to supply partial values for visionid, change it to:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Values_Select]

    @VisionId NVARCHAR(50) = null
AS
BEGIN
    if @VisionId is null set @VisionId ='%'
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT      Id, 
                VisionId, 
                Date, 
                Time, 
                [Value], 
                Checked, 
                CheckedTimestamp, 
                Vision_Name 

    FROM        dbo.viw1
    WHERE       VisionID like @VisionId

END
```